# Convert a pandas series to Integer, ignoring NaN

Tags: python, pandas

I have an expression which seems to convert my floats to ints

```
df_maa_lu.loc[df_maa_lu["APPROVAL_YEAR"].notnull()]["APPROVAL_YEAR"].apply(lambda x: int(x))
```

returns:

[image]

When I try and assign these values back it isn't working:

```
df_maa_lu.loc[df_maa_lu["APPROVAL_YEAR"].notnull()]["APPROVAL_YEAR"] = df_maa_lu.loc[df_maa_lu["APPROVAL_YEAR"].notnull()]["APPROVAL_YEAR"].apply(lambda x: int(x))
```

Returns this warning:

> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\ariel\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:1:
> SettingWithCopyWarning:  A value is trying to be set on a copy of a
> slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] =
> value instead
>
> See the caveats in the documentation:
> http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
> """Entry point for launching an IPython kernel.

And my original dataframe still has floats in it:

[image]

I tried this, but it doesn't like the "NaN" values.

```
df_maa_lu.loc[:,  "APPROVAL_YEAR"] = df_maa_lu.loc[:,  "LU_APPROVED_DT"].dt.year.apply(lambda x: int(x))
```

All I want to do is assignment on the non NaN values to int.

Comment: `df_maa_lu.loc[df_maa_lu["APPROVAL_YEAR"].notnull(),"APPROVAL_YEAR"]`

Comment: It won't matter if you change to `int` then assign back because `pandas` will still upcast the column to `float`. `np.NaN` is a float, and floats cannot be held in an Integer dtype column. You either need to accept that and work with the floats 1972.0 (this will not cause any issues as these small integers can be perfectly represented by floats, so there's no worry for inaccuracies with comparisons like `1972.0 == 1972`), or you can convert the column with `.astype('Int64')` which is pandas nullable Integer dtype.

Comment: @ALollz why can't I slice out the NaNs and just replace the rest with an integer.  That's all I am trying to do.  Do you mean that because there are NaN values in the resulting series it HAS to remain a float?

Comment: @smackenzie Yes, you slice out the nans, but the series you assign back to **still has NaN**, so those ints get upcast back to float. That's the issue. You *could* use an `object` dtype and then it will work, as object can store both float and int so the int don't get upcast, but that's a very bad idea. Converting the entire column to `'Int64'` is probably the simplest: `df_maa_lu["APPROVAL_YEAR"] = df_maa_lu["APPROVAL_YEAR"].astype('Int64')`

Comment: @ALollz happy to store them as floats if there was someway to report them as ints in the columns of a pivot table.  2020.0 is not a good look.